# Why does the read-out efficiency increase when coupling an atomic ensemble to an optical cavity?

Tags: quantum-information, atomic-physics, quantum-optics, atoms, rydberg-states

I went through a paper where it mentioned that the read-out efficiency of a quantum memory would be increased by coupling the atomic ensemble with an optical cavity.
I think rydberg atoms were used to make the atomic ensemble, and the rydberg blockade effect was used.

Can anybody explain to me, how the read-out efficiency increases?

The DOI of the paper is: [10.1109/PHOSST.2017.8012667](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8012667)

Comment: Could you link the DOI of the paper? That might be helpful in general when refering to something you took out of a publication...

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to link it,
But have added it in the body